# Javascript works on test server, but gives error on live server

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, contacts

I have a site that I've been developing on a test server which worked perfectly, but once I launched the site onto another server I get javascript errors thats preventing my contact form captcha from working thus preventing form submissions.

http://www.acgtax.com/

I tried troubleshooting the contact form and any related scripts. Id really appreciate it if someone could point me in the right direction to get this resolved.

Console errors:

```
JQMIGRATE: Logging is active jquery-migrate-1.2.1.js:21
JQMIGRATE: jQuery.attrFn is deprecated jquery-migrate-1.2.1.js:41
console.trace() jquery-migrate-1.2.1.js:43
migrateWarn jquery-migrate-1.2.1.js:43
JQMIGRATE: jQuery.fn.live() is deprecated jquery-migrate-1.2.1.js:41
console.trace() jquery-migrate-1.2.1.js:43
migrateWarn jquery-migrate-1.2.1.js:43
JQMIGRATE: jQuery.fn.attr('selected') may use property instead of attribute jquery-migrate-1.2.1.js:41
console.trace() jquery-migrate-1.2.1.js:43
migrateWarn jquery-migrate-1.2.1.js:43
event.returnValue is deprecated. Please use the standard event.preventDefault() instead.
carouFredSel: No element found for "#foo2".
```

Comment: There are **NO** JS errors on http://www.accidentphoenix.com/ at the moment

Comment: it seems that you have logging active. Deactivating it would take care of these errors

Comment: Hi @zerkms, yeah thats my point exactly. accidentphoenix is the version of the site that works. The other domain, acgtax.com, is the one that gives the errors.

Answer (score 2):

The error seems to be in your php captcha script. When you inspect the XHR request in your dev tools you can see that math-captcha.php returns

```
Fatal error: Call to undefined function: json_encode() in /home/acgtax3/public_html/lib/math-captcha.php on line 8
```

When you inspect the response headers a bit further you can see that it seems like you are running php 4.4.9 on your live server, while you run php 5.4.17 on your test server. `json_encode` was added in php 5.2 [as you can see here](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php), so I suspect you should increase the version of php on your live server to at least 5.2 that to fix the problem. Ideally the versions of your test server and your live server should be the same to prevent bugs like this when deploying.

Comment: thanks for the in-depth analysis! I dont have access to the client hosting account in order to make that php version upgrade. Before requesting that they call their hosting company update the php version to a more recent one, is there an alternative to the json_encode function for php version 4.4.9?

Comment: you realy should upgrade to at least 5.4, even if it was just for security reasons... But if you insist, I used to work with this third party class that does the encoding for you http://mike.teczno.com/JSON/doc/ available on PEAR http://pear.php.net/pepr/pepr-proposal-show.php?id=198 (did not know that still existed...)